# Can I prevent browsers from buffering CSS changes?

Tags: javascript, css

I have figured out a nice effect from application that needs several UI elements but also requires as much screen space as possible.

Idea of the effect is, that the UI buttons almost dissapear as soon as you move the mouse too away from them.
I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/hJsMR/) in case you'd like to see it.

It's quite simple:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    //Measuring distance from top-left corner of the div
    var top = rect.top+(rect.bottom-rect.top)/2;
    var left = rect.left+(rect.right-rect.left)/2;
    //Mouse position
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    //Thank pythagoras for this
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-left, 2)+Math.pow(y-top, 2));
    //Brightness in interval <1, 0.1>

    var brightness = Math.min(1, Math.max(0.1, 100/distance));

    element.style.opacity = brightness+"";  

});
```

This jsFiddle was also supposed to demonstrate problem I have - but it runs unexpectedly smoothly.

The problem is, that the browsers seem to buffer the CSS changes if they are too frequent. This is a very smart performance strategy but in my case it quite breaks the effect.

I have also uploaded [test script here.](http://u8.8u.cz/tuner/ui.php) In Google Chrome, buffering appeared to be so strong (and unsynchronized), that the buttons sometimes flickered.

Should I implement some frame-skip so that the browser buffer is not initiated by the animation effect?

<sub>My buttons have their bottom border cut off. If you'd know why this happens, please let me know in comments</sub>

Comment: Do you mean cache or buffer?

Comment: Buffer. The changes do not take effect instantly. Instead, they are rendered when I stop moving the mouse.
I believe I'm not the only one observing the effect - just check the second link.

Comment: i think the problem is more about the event dispatching. I experienced that Events are dispatched unpredictable intervals and sometimes even unsorted. I managed this using a rendering loop (with requestAnimationFrame) which generates the output ( in your case the opacity ) just for the last registered MouseEvent, this means, that you do not have to process all MouseEvents which makes it more consistent but you still have 60fps

Comment: ... and you had an event that only saved mouse position in variables?